# cPanel Directory "public_html" not allowed issue

Tags: node.js, next.js, cpanel

[image]

I want to host my next.js website on cPanel but got this error..

It is working is a subdomain.

So how can i install node.js on public_html??

Comment: Out of curiosity why cPanel? There's so many other more convenient ways to host a Next.js application. Have you looked into https://vercel.com ?

Comment: @coloradocolby i have already a shared hosting thats why I want to upload it there

Answer (score 3):

Do not put your application under the public_html directory.
The public_html directory is accessible to the public.
Putting your application code there would be an unnecessary risk.

The underlying software and configuration (Passenger) handle the mapping of the application to a publically accessible URL for you. There is zero need to place your application within the public_html folder. Instead, choose a directory named after your application or something similar.

Also, it might be helpful to know that the Node.JS plugin that you're making use of is created and provided by CloudLinux rather than cPanel:

https://docs.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux_os_components/#node-js-selector

Comment: how can i point my root domain to that directory?? because my root domain in pointed in public_html and it is not editable..

Comment: That's done with the "Application URL" field. You'll notice that there is a dropdown box where you can select your domain. mod_passenger, which is the Apache module that bridges the node.js software with Apache will map the domain you select there  to the directory that you specify in the Application Root field.

Comment: To further clarify, requests that arrive at your node.js application completely ignore the regular cPanel "Document Root",  and are instead processed and mapped to the "Application Root" by mod_passenger.

Answer (score 1):

Combining all the answers above solved my issue, I simply created a folder under public_html (name it as you like) then added the following in the Application root field

> public_html/folder_name

PS : Do not put slash before public_html

Answer (score 0):

My solution change main domain to other then add again domain app to other folder

Answer (score 0):

JUST don't put  slash replace this 'public_html/' to 'public_html'